# implement timer in my app

Tags: android, timer

i am developing a game.i want to display score on button click.but it should be displayed only for few seconds.i want to implement timer in my app.but i dnt knw how to implement that.i searched in the google.but results were confusing me...given below is my code snippet.plz anybody help me...

```
        OnClickListener clickball=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            score=scorenumber.nextInt(9);
            id=v.getId();

             Log.v("", "u clicked me");
            if(id==R.id.ball2)
            {
                ball2.setText(Integer.toString(score));
            }
            else if(id==R.id.ball3)
            {
                ball3.setText(Integer.toString(score));
            }
            else if(id==R.id.ball5)
            {
                ball5.setText(Integer.toString(score));
            }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to go so deep in your case. Every view has postDelayed() method, that will run a custom code in UI thread after a set amount of time (in milliseconds). For example:

```
ball5.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ball5.setText("");
            }
        }, 3000);
```

will clear "ball5" text after 3 seconds has passed

Another example
...

```
if(id==R.id.ball2)
            {
                ball2.setText(Integer.toString(score));
ball2.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ball2.setText("");
            }
        }, 3000);
            }
```

...

Comment: i tried this...but the thing is if i use this function it will display the score only after 3 seconds and not clearing the score...

Comment: Can you post the code?
You need to set the score first and then call postDelayed

Comment: thank u so...much Alex...it realy helps me...thanks 4 ur help

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
//Show score here

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
            //hide score here
        }
}, 2000);
```

will hide your score after two seconds.

Comment: i know u answered to my question correctly...but in this case most acceptable answer is alex's answer...sorry...anyway  thank u very much for ur great help

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CountDownTimer();` refer the documentation ,

Example :

new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

```
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //hide your score here after 5 secondes (5000/1000)
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: i know u answered to my question correctly...but in this case most acceptable answer is alex's answer...sorry...anyway  thank u very much for ur great help

Comment: Glad to hear it , we are here to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think CountDownTimer is that what you need:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html . It's quite simle for implementation

```
 new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
```

}.start();

Comment: i know u answered to my question correctly...but in this case most acceptable answer is alex's answer...sorry...anyway  thank u very much for ur great help